# Celery+Django -- KeyError Unregistered task

Tags: python, django, celery, docker-compose

I'm close to getting Celery to work with my Django+Docker-Compose project, but I have a problem where the worker never recognizes the task given to it. The basic idea is that I have a function `insertIntoDatabase` that is called from a task:

myapp/tasks.py:

```
@task(name='tasks.db_ins')
def db_ins_task(datapoints, user, description):
    from utils.db.databaseinserter import insertIntoDatabase
    insertIntoDatabase(datapoints, user, description)
```

And in `views.py`, I do:

```
from .tasks import db_ins_task
...
db_ins_task.delay(datapoints, user, description)
```

`datapoints` is basically a list of dictionaries and `user` and `description` are just strings. The problem is, when the Celery worker container starts, this `db_ins_task` is never found as one of the listed tasks, so when I try to upload anything to my website, I get the following sort of error:

```
worker_1   | [2015-09-25 19:38:00,205: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type u'tasks.db_ins'.
worker_1   | The message has been ignored and discarded.
worker_1   | 
worker_1   | Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
worker_1   | Or maybe you are using relative imports?
worker_1   | Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.
...
worker_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
worker_1   |     strategies[name](message, body,
worker_1   | KeyError: u'tasks.db_ins'
```

I've been trying to get the worker to recognize the task, including adding this setting to `settings.py`:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('myapp.tasks',)
```

I added some debug logging to `tasks.py` to make sure that it wasn't being completely missed, and I can confirm that every time I try to run the task, the logger reports that `tasks.py` is being run. For reference, here's the `worker` container in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
worker:
  build: .
  links:
    - redis
  command: bash -c "celery -A myproj worker --app=taskman.celery --loglevel=DEBUG"
```

`celery.py` is in a separate app named `taskman`. What exactly am I not doing right that would be causing this error with the tasks?

Comment: Try adding this to your config file `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`. Where app is your Celery app.

Comment: Hm, that's already in my `celery.py`. It's where I get celery to find its settings from my Django project's `settings.py`, and that part definitely works, since the `worker` container properly uses those settings.

Comment: Try calling your module like this: app = Celery('your_project',
             broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
             backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',
             include=['myapp.tasks', ])

Comment: Is there a reason to do that instead of using `settings.py`? In `celery.py` I have `app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')` which already sets things like broker, backend, and include. Also `localhost` won't work since the redis broker/backend is a container with a different IP address.

Comment: In my celery config file I had to use the config I give you above. It's in the docs.

Comment: I'm already doing the same config, though. It's already in `settings.py`. I know it's working because the logs for the celery worker show the correct IP address of the redis container for the broker and backend. The problem must be elsewhere. Would you happen to have other ideas maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you question you show starting your worker with:

```
celery -A myproj worker --app=taskman.celery --loglevel=DEBUG
```

Now, the problem is that `-A` and `--app` mean the same thing. So this suggests to me that you've been waffling between using `myproj` or `taskman.celery` as the holder of your Celery app. Your worker uses `taskman.celery`, because from testing I've found that if any combination of `-A` or `--app` are given to a single worker invocation only the last one is used.

This being said, there is one way I can imagine your problem happening. If your `myapp/tasks.py` file gets the `task` decorator from `myproj.celery.app` rather than `taskman.celery.app`, you'd be registering your tasks with the wrong app.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thanks. For further detail, what worked for me was to change the command to `celery worker --app=myapp.tasks --loglevel=DEBUG`. I also got rid of `name` from the decorator. There was also an error about too many arguments being passed to the task but uninstalling flower seemed to do the trick (I wasn't actually using flower at any point).